No matching distribution found for intel-openmp==2024.1.2
I am using a package which has intel-openmp==2024.1.2 dependecy, when I run locally on windows machine it works fine but it is not working on ubunutu(code build). it throws
No matching distribution found for intel-openmp==2024.1.2

Python verison 3.11.6
pip version 23.0.1


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+openmp You can install OpenMP on Linux but not intel-openmp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+openmp+linux , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+openmp+ubuntu

they are not supporting other os. only supporting os is WINDOWS
